# Как убрать перерисовку меню после нажатия на Menu.Item в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Используя antd у меня есть меню, Menu.Item'ы которого я формирую динамически, получая данные из БД (routes для перехода по страницам и их названия)

```
<Menu
    mode="inline"
    onOpenChange={this.onOpenChange} 
>
    {accessData?.length > 0 ? (
       <SubMenu key="sub1" title={'Docs'}>
           {accessData.map(item => (
              item.parent_route === 'docs' ?
                  <Menu.Item key={item.routeId}>
                      <Link to={item.route}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </Menu.Item> : null
            ))}
        </SubMenu>
    ) : null}
</Menu>
```

Данные получаю в методе и вызываю сразу после монтирования

```
  componentDidMount() {
       this.fetchData();
    } 
   
    fetchData = async() => {
        const { type, content: access } = await insertAccess(User.decode());
        if (type === 'ok') {
           this.setState({ accessData: access });
        } else {
           this.setState({ accessData: [] });
        }
   }
```

По нажатию на Menu.Item происходит перерендер всего меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я статически добавлю меню, то нажатия происходят без перерендера

```
        <SubMenu key="sub1" title={'Docs'}>
             <Menu.Item key="1">
                <Link to="/cabinet">'incoming'</Link>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="2">
                <Link to="/cabinet/outcoming">'outcoming'</Link>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="3">
                <Link to="/cabinet/administrative">'administrative'</Link>
              </Menu.Item>
        </SubMenu>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит, уже перерыл кучу инфы и не пойму как решить эту проблему. Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Comment: на данный момент обшей картины не вижу но у тебя меню отделено от тех компонентов которые находятся в роуте?

Comment: то есть далжно быть примерно так есть <Navbar/> где есть Link-и и есть другой компонент например <Another/>  где находятся роуты

Comment: ...По нажатию на Menu.Item происходит перерендер всего меню... такое вазможно если ты само меню поместил в роуты

Comment: @Armen меню находится в HOC, он оборачивает все страницы, и страницы находятся в Switch / Routes

Comment: винеси меню в App как отделный компонент обшей канструкцию не вижу но проблема должна исчезнуть

Comment: @Armen в HOC кроме меню еще идет логотип и layout'ы с Breadcrumb и Dropdown, для смены языка и выхода пользователя, это все тоже нужно выносить или только меню?

Comment: u menya net dostupa k kodu shtobi posmotret shto s chem svyazano vinosi menyu glyan shto vse stalo normalno i menyu ne pereresovovayetsya a ush potom to shto budet ne xvatat toje perenesi

Comment: @Armen по сути там все нужно выносить, кроме контента. Внутри HOC у меня содержится  <Content > {this.props.children} </Content> - инфа со страниц. Если я вынесу Меню и все прилагающие за Switch|Route как мне передавать страницы в HOC?

Comment: добавь ко сюда твой HOC я пока не магу понять что за архитектура у тебя ну или лутше если вазможно дай доступ к исходному коду

Comment: @Armen https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-water-mcorp?file=/src/App.js вот примерная структура проекта, я туда не накручивал всего лишнего, а только то, что относится к проблеме

Comment: @Armen потому что я накидал пример, и данные тянутся со стейта, а в реальной ситуации данные тянутся в запросе с БД

Comment: в дерево после клика добавляются новые div-ы думаю в этом проблема шя смотрю почему так

Comment: моих знаний не хватает чтобы сказать как это дело исправить вазможно есть способ как сказать чтобы меню не перересовавался но я знать не знаю, если вазможно придумай другую логику как по мне меню не должно нахадится в компоненте каторая перересовывается ... либо подожди возможно кто то более опытный найдет выход без кардиналных изминений кода ....